# Clarification on notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, notation

For a graph $G$, put $δ(G) = \text{min}\{\deg_{G} (v) : v \in V\}$ (the minimum
degree of $G$). Prove $χ(G) \leq 1 + \text{max}\{δ(G ) : G' \subseteq G\}$, where $G' \subseteq G$
means that $G$ is a subgraph of $G$

Does this mean that the chromatic number is the maximum of all of the minimum degrees of all of the possible subgraphs of G?

Please no hints on the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. This means that the chromatic number is less than or equal to the maximum of all the minimum degrees of all possible subgraphs of $G$ $+1$.

I think however that you meant to put $\delta(G')$ instead of $\delta(G)$ in the expression for the chromatic number.

Comment: thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Sorry I must edit my answer though. It only changes by the +1.

Comment: yeah, maximum degrees + 1, i omitted that myself too

Comment: @LearnToMath Sounds like we're on the same page. good luck